# python, gurobi: add constraints efficiently

Tags: python, gurobi

I am trying to optimize a model with 800+ dimensions and 3000+ inequalities in gurobipy. As I couldn't find a method for adding a whole matrix as constraints, I add them with the following code:

```
for index,inequality in enumerate(inequalities):
    expression = 0
    for index2,variable in enumerate(inequality):
        expression += variable*x[index2]
    m.addConstr(expression >= rhs[index])
```

with x being the variables. This part of the programs needs 70+ seconds, while the problem is optimized in a fraction of seconds. can someone point me in a direction on how to add the constraints more efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to improve the time to below one second due to the fact that almost all of the matrix consists of zeros by changing the line

```
for index2,variable in enumerate(inequality):
```

to

```
for index2,variable in [(index2,variable) for index2,variable in enumerate(inequality) if variable!=0]:
```

as only a tiny fraction of the operations need to be run. I would still be interested in a cleaner way of adding these constraints to my model